# solving equations (lagrange multipliers)

Tags: calculus

A rectangular box with no top has volume $V=xyz$

The material used for the bottom and front of the box is 5 times as expensive as the back and other two sides.

What should the dimensions to minimize the cost of the materials?

$$L=f(x,y,z)+\lambda g(x,y,z)$$

$$f(x,y,z)= 5xy + 6xz+2yz$$

$$g(x,y,z)=xyz-V$$

how can I solve the equations?

$$5y+6z+\lambda yz=0$$

$$5x+2z+\lambda xz=0$$

$$6x+2y+\lambda xy=0$$

$$xyz-V=0$$

Comment: Get rid of lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the system:
$$5y+6z+\lambda yz=0$$

$$5x+2z+\lambda xz=0$$

$$6x+2y+\lambda xy=0$$

$$xyz-V=0$$

Multiply first equation by $x$:

$$5xy+6xz+ \lambda V =0$$

Multiply second equation by $y$:
$$5xy +2yz+ \lambda V = 0$$
Multiply third equation by $z$:
$$6xz+2yz+ \lambda V= 0$$

We can see that $3x=y$ and $5y=6z$, that is we can express $x$ and $z$ in terms of $y$.

From $xyz=V$, you should be able to compute $x$, $y$, and $z$.